# Symmetry of the output of fft2 command in matlab

Tags: matlab, fft, fftw

When I run in matlab

```
fft2([9.36,-3.42,-2.12;-3.42 0.8 3.68 ;-0.6 -3.88 -4.96 ; 2.82 0.52 2.82])
```

I obtain

```
    1.6000 +  0.0000i      11.4400 +  4.6765i      11.4400 -  4.6765i
   13.2600 +  5.1000i       8.8123 +  8.8711i       7.8077 +  4.7489i
  -12.8400 +  0.0000i      20.4600 -  4.2955i      20.4600 +  4.2955i
   13.2600 -  5.1000i       7.8077 -  4.7489i       8.8123 -  8.8711i
```

What is the symmetry of this last matrix? I know that in the fft there exists some symmetry used to do not store all the information of the matrix, and I need to know what is the symmetry of the matrices output of the command fft2.

Some of context (I do not if is useful for the question/answer):
I need understand this because the output of the Fast Fourier Transform using [fttw3 library](http://www.fftw.org/) I obtain the vector

```
  1.6
  13.26  + 5.1i
 -12.84
  11.44  + 4.6765i
  8.8123 + 8.871i
  20.46  - 4.2955i
  11.44  - 4.6765i
  7.8077 + 4.7488i
  20.46  + 4.2955i
  ***
  ***
  ***
```

As you see, are almost all the elements of the initial matrix, but I do not have the last row, and I think that this values could be calculated using some symmetry.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a symmetry property for the _one-dimensional_ DFT (FFT). For two dimensions, the DFT is equivalent to a one-dimensional DFT along each column followed by another DFT along each row of the result (or vice versa). Since the result of the first DFT is complex, it seems difficult to identify any symmetries

Comment: It can easily be derived how to fill in the 2nd half of the 2D FFT (complex conjugate and mirror of each image line in the first half), but if you need those values in your array, just compute a complex-to-complex 2D FFT, it’s a lot easier.

Comment: @CrisLuengo it was the best advice ever !!!!   Thanks a lot.